# How the object refers to itself?

Tags: python, object, reference, garbage-collection

```
def create_cycle(): 

    # create a list x 

    x = []

    # A reference cycle is created 

    # here as x contains a reference to 

    # to self. 

    x.append(x) 


create_cycle()
```

> Because create_cycle() creates an object x which refers to itself, the object x will not automatically be freed when the function returns. This will cause the memory that x is using to be held onto until the Python garbage collector is invoked.

Can somebody please explain how the object refers to itself? Please explain in detail what the above post says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you assign an object, such as a list, to a variable, the object isn't copied, but instead a *reference* is created to the object.  You can think of it as a pointer.  For example:

```
a = []
b = a
```

This creates an empty list, and assigns a reference to that list to `a`.  The following assignment creates a second reference to the list in `b`.  If you change the list, e.g. `a.append(5)`, the list becomes `[5]`.  Since both `a` and `b` reference the list, they both have the same value.

References can also come from within objects, such as lists.  For example:

```
a = []
b = [a]
```

This creates two lists.  The first is an empty list, with a reference to it from `a`.  The second is a list containing a single element, which is a second reference to `a`.  If you again do `a.append(5)`, then the first list becomes `[5]` and the second becomes `[[5]]`.

Now suppose you instead do the following:

```
a = []
a.append(a)
```

The first statement again creates an empty list, referenced by `a`.  The second then modifies that list by appending a value to it.  But in this case, rather than appending a number, or a reference to a different list, it instead appends a reference to the list itself.  So the list ends up containing a single element, which is a reference to the list itself.  This is a cyclic reference.  If you try to print `a`, it would just keep chasing the reference deeper and deeper without end, but Python detects the cycle and just shows `...` to indicate the cycle.

Cycles affect garbage collection in Python.  Python keeps a reference count of each object.  Each time a new reference to an object is created, the reference count for that object is increased.  When a reference is removed (e.g., by assigning a different value to a variable references an object, or by a variable going out of scope), the reference count is decremented.  When it reaches zero, Python knows it's free to garbage collect (i.e., free) that object.  In doing so, any objects it references also have their reference count decremented.  In general, an entire tree of references can be deallocated in this manner.

But if the reference graph is not a tree, i.e. if it contains a cycle, this doesn't work.  For instance, you can end up with a cycle of objects that reference each other, each with a reference count of 1.  To handle this case, a mark-and-sweep garbage collection pass is needed.  This traverses all references to see which are reachable.  It then frees anything that is unreachable, even if its reference count is non-zero.

Comment: Such a great answer!!

Comment: Just to make sure if I got it correctly - so the ```[]``` (empty list) contains two references; one which is outside the instance of the ```list``` class and another which is contained inside the instance of the ```list``` class - both named ```x```. The reference count is ```2```. So when the work of the function ```create_cycle()``` is over, the reference count is decremented by ```1```, since the outer reference ```a``` is deallocated.

Comment: But the memory allocated for the ```instance``` of the ```list``` class is not collected since the inner reference ```x``` remains, making the reference count ```1``` - which is not zero, right? Please tell me.

Comment: @NirajRaut Well, it starts as an empty list `[]`, assigned to `x`.  At that point it has a reference count of 1.  If the function returned at that point, `x` would go out of scope, the reference count would drop to 0, and it would be immediately freed.  But instead, it then appends `x` to the list, which is the list itself.  The list is no longer `[]` at that point, it's `[x]` where `x` is a reference to the list.  If you tried to expand it, it would look like `[[[[[[...]]]]]]`.  I.e. it would appear to be an infinite nest. (cont.)

Comment: @NirajRaut (cont.)  There is still only one list, but now the reference count is 2:  One from the variable `x`, and a second one from the first (and only) element of the list itself.  If the function returns now, the reference count will drop to 1, and the list will be orphaned.  The memory won't be reclaimed until Python does a garbage collection pass, at which time it will detect that the list is inacessible and will free it.

Comment: @NirajRaut Note that you can have more complex cyclic references that involve multiple objects.  For example:  `a = []; b = [a]; a.append(b)`.  This results in two mutually-referential lists:  The list referenced by `a` references the list referenced by `b` and vice versa.  Again, if the function returns, the two lists each have a reference count of 1, and the storage won't be reclaimed until a garbage collection pass is performed.

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between an instance and an object? I have searched on the web but everyone has a different interpretation which confuses me. Please tell me.

Comment: @NirajRaut They're basically the same thing.  If you create 5 lists, you've creates 5 list instances.  The same thing goes for a class.  The class itself is also an object, but you wouldn't normally refer to it as an instance.  But each time you create an instance of the class, e.g. `x = ClassName(...)`, you've created a new instance.

Comment: What is right? - an ```instance``` of a class or an ```object``` of a class. Class is an instance of metaclass, right?

Comment: @NirajRaut Both a class and an instance of a class are objects.  The term "object" is pretty broad.  Basically everything is an object.  An instance is a narrower term.  You wouldn't refer to an "object of a class".  This is getting pretty far off-topic though.  You can probably find some Python documentation that defines these terms more precisely.

Comment: @NirajRaut You might find this useful:  [Python data model](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html)

Comment: @NirajRaut A heap is strictly more powerful than a stack, since it allows freeing in any order, while a stack requires that only the most recently allocated item may be freed.  In the case of Python, a pure call stack doesn't suffice because Python supports closures.  This means that a given frame may remain active even after the function returns.

Comment: Hey, please answer this question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61835719/13469230